# Remove dictionary key if any item of the tuple that composes it is not in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dict and a df that as the following below:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import scipy.spatial.distance as ssd
import numpy as np

dict_edge = {(1,2): {'Duration': 1.17, 'Numcalls':4},
             (3,2): {'Duration': 1.27, 'Numcalls':3},
             (3,4): {'Duration': 1.3, 'Numcalls':2}}

df = pd.DataFrame({'SJDR': [0,0,0,1],
                   'TR': [0,0,2,1],
                   'LD': [1,3,0,0]})
```

I need add another item in `dict_edge.values()`, and for that I use the following iteration:

```
for key, value in zip(dict_edge.keys(), dict_edge.values()):
    x = df.loc[key[0]].to_numpy()
    y = df.loc[key[1]].to_numpy()
    cosine = 1 - ssd.cosine(x,y)
    value['Cosine_Similarity'] = cosine
```

however, due to the fact that the dataframe has no index of value 4, I get the key error. So, what I need to do is check if all the items of all the tuples that make up the `dict_edge` keys are in the `df` dataframe index. Otherwise, I want to delete the entire item (key and value) referring to the tuple's item key that is not in the dataframe. After this filtering, the desired dict_edge would look like this:

```
dict_edge = {(1,2): {'Duration': 1.17, 'Numcalls':4},
             (3,2): {'Duration': 1.27, 'Numcalls':3}}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether all the keys are in the index:

```
for key, value in zip(dict_edge.keys(), dict_edge.values()):
    if pd.Series(key).isin(df.index).all():
        x = df.loc[key[0]].values
        y = df.loc[key[1]].values
        cosine = 1 - ssd.cosine(x,y)
        value['Cosine_Similarity'] = cosine
    else:
        value['Cosine_Similarity'] = np.NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```py
import copy

import pandas as pd

...
# Iterate on a copy of dict_edge and remove unwanted keys in orginal dict_edge
for key in copy.deepcopy(dict_edge).keys():
    if max(key) > df.shape[0] - 1:
        del dict_edge[key]

print(dict_edge)
# Outputs
{(1, 2): {"Duration": 1.17, "Numcalls": 4}, (3, 2): {"Duration": 1.27, "Numcalls": 3}}
```